# passing an argument into a C++ shared library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, visibility

I want to pass an argument into a C++ shared library lib.so form loader.exe.

**Sorry, update the question.**

shared library like:

```
int count(){
         int num = 9;
         int result = 0;
         for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ ){
                 result ++;
         }
         return result;
}
```

In the loader.exe, use a dlopen to load it.

```
void *handler = dlopen("lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

I want to change the value of num from loader.exe. when I call the function count(), it can give me the new result.

How should I do?

thanks!

Comment: This question is insane. It doesn't even make sense if there weren't any shared libraries involved.

Comment: @user2413399: I have updated my answer.  Please check it out.

Comment: And yes, as Kerrek said, this question is in fact shared-library irrevalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable `num` (set to the desired value) in your loader program and change

```
     int num = 9;
```

to

```
     extern int num;
```

.